# Setting up the superuser password for the first time

Tags: password, authentication

How can I set up the super user password for the first time in Zorin OS, since the installer didn't ask me to provide one. I have experience with Fedora and openSUSE, but they asked me for the superuser's password during the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this looks like a Linux distribution.  Presuming that your non-root user has `sudo` privileges, if you want to set the root password, you can do so with `sudo passwd root` or `sudo -s` followed by `passwd`.

Comment: Zorin looks like it's based on Ubuntu; in that case, sudo should work by default, and to get a root prompt use `sudo -i` (equivalent to `su -`). It's not needed to set the root password.